# Understanding cost-sensitive evaluation in Weka (cost matrix)

Tags: weka

I am using Weka 3.7.1

I am attempting to analyze sport predictions for baseball using weka. I would like to use a cost matrix because the cost of different outcomes is not the same at a sportsbook where I gamble on the game. My data set is simple: it is a set of predictions with a nominal class {WIN,LOSS}. For this question, the attributes are not a concern.

In the WEKA Explorer, after loading my arff file I can setup a cost matrix from

> Classify->More Options...->Cost-sensitive evaluation->Set...->There is
>   a 2x2 grid that appears in the weka cost-sensitive evaluation after I
>   set the classes == 2

Here are the values I would like to enter in to the cost matrix:

- Correctly classified as loss, cost is 0 (I did not wager)
- Incorrectly classified as loss, cost is 0 (I did not wager)
- Correctly classified as win, cost is -.909 (I won .909 dollars)
- Incorrectly classified as win, cost is 1.0 (I lost a dollar)

Observe that to stay true with it being a 'cost matrix' that I set my profit to a negative value (which is the opposite of cost, it is a profit); and that I set the loss to a positive number (because it cost me when I lost the wager).

After some reflection I decided to use the following grid, and I have not a clue if I did this correctly, please let me know if I did this correctly:

```
 - a   b       <---- "classified as"
 - 0   1.0     a=LOSS
 - 0   -.909   b=WIN
```

And here is my probably faulty logic: (col, row)

```
(0,0) of grid=0: classified as LOSS, and was LOSS
(0,1) of grid=0: classified as LOSS, but was WIN
(1,0) of grid=1.0; classified as WIN, but was LOSS
(1,1) of grid=.909; classified as WIN, was WIN
```

and of course (0,0) and (0,1) represent the classifier predicting a LOSS and in these cases I do not wager, and therefore there is no cost.

on the other hand (1,0) and (1,1) represent the classifier predicting a WIN and in these cases I place a wager, and therefore there is a cost associated.

One other item that is of great confusion: after I setup the cost matrix and execute a classifier, the output report contains the following:

Evaluation cost matrix:

```
 0    1   
 0    0.91   <--- notice that this is not a negative value!
```

And as you can see, in the report (1,1) is 0.91 when I had actually entered -.909. I did find another post about this topic, but it does not explain why the negative value became positive.

Thank you in advance. Please note that these are answerable questions; however, if you want to provide some guidance I would be very happy as I am a newbie still trying to build a framework of understanding.

Comment: Hi, I was going to ask this exact question. Did you come to a conclusion? Does this work? It appears to work when I put values into the Cost/Benefit Analysis window on Weka, like so. http://www.dowce.com/~ZbX Any help is greatly appreciated :) -Jason

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't figured this one out. I think the answer would stem from understanding the underlying math model. Specifically, how do the values in the cost matrix interact with a classifier? You can see in user3598769's post that he indicates confusion about using a negative value for the cost. But in the context of baseball wagering, it makes perfect sense. If you figure out the proper way to use it please post back and I'll give you the points.

Comment: for my context it makes perfect sense as well, I dont recall anything in any documentation about this being 'bad'. I think it might be down to how the classifier is implem3ented whether it has some assumption of cost functions being of the form that user3598769 intimated/expected. In the case of the AveragedNDependenceEstimator it seems to work in the UI. I just wonder what's going on under the hood with some of these algorithms so I'm considering figuring out the eclipse environment so I can breakpoint inside the classifier in the debugger to see what's really going on.

Comment: With the AveragedNDependenceEstimator I think it uses the cost matrix to direct the classification task. Making decisions based on minimum error if I recall correctly.. which means that it is imperative that the cost matrix is handled as I specify it and not with some kind of fudge..

Answer (score 6):

Cost matrix is a way to change the threshold value for decision boundary. 
It is explained in a following paper.

http://research.ijcaonline.org/volume44/number13/pxc3878677.pdf

By looking at your cost matrix it seems that there is a little correction required.

e.g.

```
0    cost
cost 0
```

just for explanation:
consider following cost matrix:

```
a b
c d
```

This is the general format of cost matrix which I have observed for two class problems.

now when you have classified something at a or d location then there is no need to incorporate the cost.

So the point here is, the cost comes in picture only when there is a misclassification. i.e. either at b or c location.

But as you have written negative value as a cost at place d it creates confusion. (kindly make it possible to explain the same, i.e. what do you mean by negative cost.)

an example cost matrix can be:

```
0  1
10 0
```

which says that cost of classifying examples as false positive is 10 times higher than the cost of misclassification of similar example as false negative. Moreover there is no cost when examples are classified correctly.